# Entering the country(Japan) after the visa starting date

Tags: visas, japan

Can I enter Japan after the visa (Japan) starting date? As due to some reason, I may get the visa a little late and I have to book another plane on a later date (4-5 days after the visa starting date). Will this be possible? The return date remains the same. Thank you!

Comment: Why would that be a problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. You can enter the country on any day between the first and the last day of your visa validity period.

But how many times you can enter the country, depends on the art of the visa (single entry, double entry, multiple entry).